# Clipping multiple layers to a set frame? (CoreAnimation/Quartz2d)

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

Im not sure how to word this, or what the correct terminology is. Hopefully I can explain...

Setup:

- Basically I have a UIView made up of multiple CALayers.
- Each layer has an object on it (custom drawn with a Draw method override)
- I animate using a scale transform (ie: grow), so it
  grows until it expands past the full size of the frame of the parent
- **I what each layer to be clipped when it reaches the edge of the UIView, so it doesn't display past the border of the UIView**

Hopefully this image can explain what im trying to do:
[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the clipsToBounds property off? From the UIView docs:

> clipsToBounds A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are
>   confined to the bounds of the receiver.
>
> @property(nonatomic) BOOL clipsToBounds
>
> Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.

You can turn this on by setting the property in code, or if the view comes from a xib file there's a "Clips Subviews" checkbox in the Attributes inspector in Interface Builder.